# How to enable void "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and disable it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, radio-button

I search didSelectRowAtIndexPath this key word

And found most problem is how to trigger it

But my question is how to enable it with another conditions

You can check my last question here - [How to add a radio button in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213710/add-radio-button-in-tableview-got-some-problem)

how To disable this void when the radio button is not selected ???

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question, but from what I can tell, you want to prevent a tableView row from being selected under certain conditions? For that you'll want to use `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. If you return `nil` from that method the tableView will not select a row. You may find it helpful to read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: so I have to declare this method tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: and call it after check the button is selected or not ?

Comment: Thank you ! I will try both answer 謝謝

Comment: You don't have to declare anything. tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: is declared in UITableViewDelegate. If you implement it it will be called before the tableView attempts to select a row. I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to do though.

Comment: I need a table view ,with two selection,and only one can be selected when using ,if the radio button is not selected ,it won't work .that's why I have to disable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you need to run the code within the method conditionally. If your radiobutton is enabled, just run it, if not, return nil (or the other way round). You cannot prevent the method from being called at all, however.

Answer (score 0):

according to your radio button state set the cell property

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: well....this can disable the response of row selection ,but my default radio button is all set off...so I can't even trigger any one of them

Comment: Be aware that if you use `userInteractionEnabled` on a `UITableViewCell`, the text color will change, and you can't do anything about that.