# How to disable didSelectRowAtIndexPath on UIView Tap inside custom TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `TableViewCell` inside that custom `UITableViewCell` there is a `UIView`(`myView`). I want to disable `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when I tap on `myView`,`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`should not be called when I tap on `myView`.

it's not same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244675) because in that question it's not clear what the user want to achieve and also answer is different.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244675/how-to-enable-void-didselectrowatindexpath-and-disable-it

Comment: You can not disable the execution of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function. What you can do here add a `UITapGesture` on your `myView` and perform the desired task.

Comment: @VijayMasiwal See Bannings answer its working fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `pointInside` of UITableViewCell, try this:

```
// MyCell.m
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL pointInside = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];

    if (pointInside && ![self.myView pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:self.myView] withEvent:event]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPathshould` not be called when u tap on myView

Answer (score 2):

Accodding to [the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/) say

> iOS uses hit-testing to find the view that is under a touch. Hit-testing involves checking whether a touch is within the bounds of any relevant view objects. If it is, it recursively checks all of that view’s subviews. The lowest view in the view hierarchy that contains the touch point becomes the hit-test view. After iOS determines the hit-test view, it passes the touch event to that view for handling.
>   
> In the image blow :

(Figure 2-1  Hit-testing returns the subview that was touched)
 [image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Art/hit_testing_2x.png))</sub>

To illustrate, suppose that the user touches view E in Figure 2-1. iOS finds the hit-test view by checking the subviews in this order:

1. The touch is within the bounds of view A, so it checks subviews B
   and    C.
2. The touch is not within the bounds of view B, but it’s within the
   bounds of view C, so it checks subviews D and E.
3. The touch is not within the bounds of view D, but it’s within the
   bounds of view E. View E is the lowest view in the view hierarchy
   that contains the touch, so it becomes the hit-test view.

As most app do,there is no need to disable the execution of didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.What you can do here ,is to add a `UIButton` or add a UITapGesture on your myView and perform the desired task,when you touch in the area of the UITapGesture, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will not execute.
Just like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for explanation I did as you said I have a button created programmatically  in myView and it has an action added to it  but when I tap on that button it only perform didSelectRowAtIndexPath don't know why